# java.lang.NullPointerException in mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop

I have created a class as detect harm which I tested to work in normal environment. The class is such that you have to provide problem statement & device type and the result is a code. This code logic is defined in a function with private variable. This variable is initialized everytime the object is created an a file containing values is passed.

I have used the same idea in mapreduce program where in for every input split an object would be created of the class. The rule file would be passed and the value would be returned. I see that the intermediate functions are returning perfect values only problem is the mapping of the function which returns the hashmap code.

```
public HashMap<String,String> fdpCodes(LinkedList<String> str)
{

    HashMap<String,String> displayCodes = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(String word:str)
    {
        if(mapHarms.containsKey(word))
            displayCodes.put(mapHarms.get(word),word);
    }

    if(displayCodes.isEmpty()) displayCodes.put("C50675", "No Harm");   


    return displayCodes;

}
```

I have to declare the same logic in hadoop to make it work. Any suggession is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: on which line is the NPE ? Please provide the stack trace

Comment: do not have the stack trace.. I did a work around but when i kind of debugged i came to know that the error is on if(mapHarms.containsKey(word)) line because the value in the mapHarm <hashmap> is not retaining the value when its processed in hadoop. onemore thing i did is i tried to create a similar type of variable in mapper and populate it with the distributed catch object and then use it. But same error.

Comment: In which part of the code do you populate mapHarms? If that is a constant list of words? If so, just populate the list from a HDFS file/Distribute cache in the setup method.

Comment: I tried that too.. but still it goes blank.. As i populate i tried to display the values but it comes null... I dont know why.. So the turn around was quite childish, i make the value in a function and every time populated for each map.. Since the values are just 60 in numbers I managed it.